# MariaDB ignores binlog_format

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to make moodle work on my system, so i need to change bin_log format to MIXED or ROW.

But, i'm having a lot of problems doing that. Any changes i try to do don't work;

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'binlog_format'
    -> ;
+---------------+-----------+
| Variable_name | Value     |
+---------------+-----------+
| binlog_format | STATEMENT |
+---------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'ROW';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'binlog_format'
    -> ;
+---------------+-----------+
| Variable_name | Value     |
+---------------+-----------+
| binlog_format | STATEMENT |
+---------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And i've also set binlog_format=row on my.cnf.
One weird thing i noticied is that it seems that the basedir is wrong. the mariadb basedir is /etc/mysql, but it shows /usr as basedir:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'basedir';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| basedir       | /usr  |
+---------------+-------+
```

Anyone knows what the problem can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Global" settings are initial values for when you login.  You failed to log out and log back in, hence it still said `STATEMENT`.

`/etc/` is a place for configuration-like stuff, *not* for `basedir`.

`/usr` does not seem right for basedir, either.  Perhaps `/usr/mysql` or `/usr/mariadb`?

Comment: I also did think that /etc/mysql is a very strange place fot a basedir, but here is what my /usr folder contains: bin  games  include  lib  local  sbin  share  src
And my /etc/mysql folder: conf.d  debian.cnf  debian-start  my.cnf
I did also spin up a new VPS and installed only MariaDB again from scratch, same thing happens. Logging out and back in, restarting the service, restarting the server, nothing did make the options stick, even with the my.cnf still saying "row".

Comment: `my.cnf` is a text file that contains configuration settings for MySQL or MariaDB.

Comment: What arguments are on the running `mysqld` service?

Comment: So what the basedir contains? I'm going to check the arguments, just a minute

Comment: usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --skip-log-error --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306

Comment: Adding `--defaults-file /etc/mysql/my.cnf` to the script that invoked that _may_ be a solution.  Or, perhaps it is expecting it at `/etc/my.cnf`.

Comment: UPDATE: I'm dumb. I forgot to delete the # before the binlog_format in the my.cnf. now it works just fine.